# Too many positional arguments when i use admob flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, admob

why i get this error
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (Documentation)  Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments

**final ams = AdMobService();**

here in this code:
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (Documentation)  Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments

`@override void initState() { Admob.initialize(ams.getAdMobAppId()); }`

````
  String getAdMobAppId() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-2334510780816542~6726672523';
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-2334510780816542~7385148076';
    }
    return null;
  }

  String getInterstitialAdUnitId() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910';
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';
    }
    return null;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Dart supports "positional" arguments and "named" arguments. Positional arguments are given by just using their position, but named arguments are provided like: `name: value`. For example:

```
void myCustomFunction(
  String name,  // positional argument
  {int? age,}   // named argument
) {
  // function body
}
```

You could then call this function like:

```
myCustomFunction("hello");  // "hello" is passed in to the parameter "name"
myCustomFunction(
  "hello",  // positional argument (1st argument in list)
  age: 10,  // named argument (we provide the name "age")
)
```

This error is saying "you gave me 1 positional argument, but the function didn't expect any positional arguments". To fix it, you need to do one of two possible things:

1. If `Admob.initialize()` has no parameters, just use `Admob.initialize()`
2. If `Admob.initialize()` has a named parameter for the API key, you will have to use something like `Admob.initialize(apiKey: "your api key")` (note that the actual name `apiKey` might be different, take a look at the documentation for admob)